# JQuery navigation menu authorization

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create navigation menu in my MVC application using Jquery. I am using http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/ for this.

However I want to display menu items based on user roles i.e. including asp membership authorization logic so that if the user does not have the required role, he does not see certain menu items.

Can anyone suggest how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I may be wrong but I think the menu will be visible and if a user who doesnot have permission to access a particular page clicks the menu item he might b redirected to Access Denied page , again My opinion.

Comment: Yes that can be done, but I do not want to display the menu item itself if a user is not allowed to see the page. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since superfish only works client side you need to make sure it only has the right html in the first place, which you define server-side.

Your role provider has a IsUserInRole and GetRolesForUser. You could use that to build up the HTML.

For instance:

```
@if (RoleProvider.IsUserInRole(user.username, "admin")) {
    <li>Admin<li>
}
```

Comment: As pointed out in other comments, what I've done above isn't necessarily the most efficient, but it is simple and clear, and ensures that the client never sees menu items they shouldn't. It might be a security consideration for you that menu items a user should never see never even make it to their browser. (And of course having javascript turned off will only make your menu ugly here, but it'll still have the correct items.) You should definitely consider caching the response, although IsUserInRole would normally be cached so it's not causing a database look-up every visit.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: This answer is more appropriate if you're doing a lot of client-side stuff and communicating with the MVC application only for data. If you're rendering every page from the server then use the answer from Steve.

I think you'll need to communicate the user's roles to the client-side using a controller action that returns JsonResult. E.g.

```
public class SecurityController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Roles()
    {
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(),
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```

Then use `$.ajax` to retrieve the data client-side and in the callback remove nodes from the DOM that don't match your requirements. E.g.

> 

```
    <ul id="menu">
        <li data-roles="Administrator">
            Secured
        </li>
        <li>Any</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: "security/roles",
            success: function(roles) {
                $("#menu li[data-roles]").filter(function() {
                    var requiredRoles = (this.attr("data-roles") || "").split(",");
                    for (var requiredRole in requiredRoles) {
                        if (roles.indexOf(requiredRole) >= 0) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }).remove();

                // TODO call your menu plugin here
                // $("#menu").superfish();
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#menu li[data-roles]").remove();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Cheers,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

If you have the users/roles set up in database then you can create tables, one table will contain the menus and the other one will map the menus with the roles.

You may have to create a child action that will query the database get the menu items for a particular role and renders the menu through a partial view. You can even keep the menu items for a user in session and by that way you can avoid hitting the db on each request.

Hiding the menu items partly solves the problem. You have to use the Authorize filter to secure controllers and actions.